How to remove space area when transform use in flutter
in this code i have to use transform matrix diagonal when the bool value true that time both side and top some space show because use the scale 0.90 but how to remove this space.
 child: Transform(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                // transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(isKeyboardVisible?_scale*0.90:_scale,isKeyboardVisible?_scale*0.90:_scale, 1.0),
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(
                  isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                      ? _scale * 0.90
                      : _scale,
                  isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                      ? _scale * 0.90
                      : _scale,
                  1.0,
                )..translate(_position.dx * (isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value ? 0.90 : 1.0),
                  _position.dy * (isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value ? 0.90 : 1.0),),
              child: Stack(
                  children: [

                       Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),


                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 5 / 7,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                                ? Alignment.topCenter // Align to top center when condition is true
                                : Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.white,

                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    ...GlobalState.movableAllWidgets,


                  ]
              ),
            ),

in this image bool is false it is ok red container is cover full screen and white container with padding.

but when bool value is true that time some space show and container not go up this space container cut in this space.


here u should try this maybe this will help u
child: Transform(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                // transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(isKeyboardVisible?_scale*0.90:_scale,isKeyboardVisible?_scale*0.90:_scale, 1.0),
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(
                  isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                      ? _scale * 0.90
                      : _scale,
                  isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                      ? _scale * 0.90
                      : _scale,
                  1.0,
                )..translate(_position.dx * (isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value ? 0.90 : 1.0),
                  _position.dy * (isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value ? 0.90 : 1.0),),
              child: Stack(
                  children: [

                       Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
Positioned.fill(
child:Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 5 / 7,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: isKeyboardVisible || controller.isBottomVisible.value
                                ? Alignment.topCenter // Align to top center when condition is true
                                : Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.white,
  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ...GlobalState.movableAllWidgets,
    ],
  ),
),

hope it will help u..
i have used Positioned.fill

it is not work. if use this its cover full area of white container.
